# read text from uploaded file - c# and javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, file-upload, filereader

I have something like this:

```
<form action="" id="fileUpload">
    <input type="file" id="fileTest"/>
    <input type="button" id="saveFile"/>   </form>
```

For the user to upload a file.

I then have this js:

```
$('#saveFile').click(function () {
    PageMethods.ReadFile($('#fileTest').val());
});
```

And in my c# code i do this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void ReadFile(string path)
{
    try
    {
        // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
        // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            String line;
            // Read and display lines from the file until the end of
            // the file is reached.
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Let the user know what went wrong.
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

But the path that is sent to the webMethod is not the correct path of the file.

I am just trying to get the data from the file and then do with it somethings.

Is this the way to do it? If so, how can i get this to work?

Or is there a better way of doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: what path are you getting.. are you getting the path of the webserver or the absolute path of where the actual file you are expecting resides or neither..? also for the file type shouldn't that be something like text/"bla bla bla what ever other option it expects in a web upload..?

Comment: I am geeting this path: `c:\fakepath\myFile.txt`. didnt understand the second question.

Comment: what path are you expecting then

Comment: there c:\ is local you need a server file path also I know it's not necessary but you may want to add a sr.Close() after your While loop for your file

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to access a client-side file (`$('#fileTest')`) on the server.  This isn't possible.

Instead, you'll need to POST the upload form to the web server and handle it on that end.

Comment: Thanks, can you please write the exact code i will need for doing that??? That will be a big help.

Comment: All you need to do is have the file post to the server.  Make the form post using JQuery.

Comment: Reading this article should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are sending the local file path to webservice and then trying to read the file content. This is not possible. The webserver cannot view or access your local folders. You would need to upload the file and then you can use a webservice call the get back the data of successfully uploaded file.

Comment: How do i upload the file?? can you please write for me in more details? Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="MyPage/MyWebMethod.aspx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" id="fileTest"/>
    <input type="button" id="saveFile"/>
</form>
```

then on the server you can access the files from Request.Files. Or something like that. i don't remember the exact member off of Request. also ajax isn't straight forward with file uploads. there are many tricks with uploading files in an ajax manner, one of which is using iframes.

Comment: Thanks. I am using asp.net, how do i get this to the server? how would the server method look?

Comment: google is your friend here. in the page method get the current request from the current context, then access the file from the Files collection off of the request.